# Button with custom XML layout

Tags: android, xml, button

Is it possible to create a button with a custom xml layout?

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="1dp"
  android:background="#7e7e7e">

 <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:background="#f9f9f9">

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:text="ButtText"
  android:textColor="#000000">
 </TextView>

 <ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:background="@drawable/arrow"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
 </ImageView>

 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to use this on a button.  Anyone know how I can do this?
I was thinking if I had Button.java file that extended Button. And then setView(R.layout.mylayout.xml);   ...  but that was to easy, and it clearly not working

Regards Martin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot literally use that layout on the face of a `Button`. You can achieve a similar look using the `android:drawableRight` property on a `Button`, though.

Comment: everything is so easy. Thank u for info of today!  :)

Answer (score 26):

I've been dealing with this recently because I wanted to put two textviews in a button. You have to choose:

1. Extend Button class and use it in your layout
2. Use a Layout insted of a button and drag inside everithing you need and make it clickable by adding this parametter to it:

   ```
   android:clickable="true"
   ```

After that you can modify te apperance of your layout by defining the

```
android:background="@drawable/my_background"
```

to give to it a "button-like" face and behavior

/res/drawable/mi_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/black"/> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/black" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/> 
 </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout to simply overlay your custom button view on top of a real Button like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Your custom button layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#7e7e7e"
        android:padding="1dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f9f9f9"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="ButtText"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/jobs_menu" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```