# Android custom gridview layout (textview with imageview on top)

Tags: android, gridview, layout

I'm trying to work out how to create the layout for a gridview for my game. I have a gridview which will be the level selector. At the moment I have each gridview item as a TextView, just showing the Level Number (1, 2, 3, etc).

I would like to add 3 imageviews over the top of the textview and be able to manipulate the image shown in the views. The 3 image views are stars, showing what difficulty the level was completed on.

I figure I need to write my own Adapter and inflate the XML layout when creating the views for the grid items but I'm stuck with how to create the actual layout for this, the overlapping part has me scratching my head?

Here's a mockup of what I've tried to describe, and what I want to create:
[image]

PS. I know I could use 4 images and set the textview background to one of those images but I wondered if there was a more technical way of creating the layout.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I went with the un-technical 4 images in the end, it was simple and easy and there aren't any issues scrolling through the grid so it's all good.

Comment: It was an answer to my question, the answer I used to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [relative view!](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html)

The basics would be, define your button background Bitmap/Drawable with the #1 on it, and then, for each button, have a layout with the copper, silver and gold stars.  You can use        `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on the Copper start and base the other alignments off of that one.  Then you just set the stars drawable based on if the star is toggled on or of.

I'm going to use rough psuedo code here:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="button1">
  <ImageView android:id="copper_star" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
  <ImageView android:id="silver_star" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_rightOf="@id/copper_star"/>
   ...etc...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Once you've got it looking the way you want, you can see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333996/button-with-custom-xml-layout) by Mark Murphy.  He explains how to set the properties of a button to do what you'd like.

Comment: Hm, I don't really want to create the background with the level number on it. It's not too practical as every time there's a new level I'll have to make a new background. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Alternatively, just create a TextView in the  center with a number being the level.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just looking at the parent aligns, I think I can work with that, experimentation begins...