# How to place Text on an ImageView inside a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, textview, imageview

I've followed the tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

I'm wondering how I get place text over the images in this gridview?  I've seen other examples here @ stackoverflow but they are with [linearlayouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777749/how-to-set-text-over-an-imageview) or they gave up and just made custom images for each like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788211/android-custom-gridview-layout-textview-with-imageview-on-top).  Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best approach, but I would try to return a layout (which is an indirect subclass of `View`) that encapsulates both the `ImageView` containing the image and a `TextView` with the overlaying text.

So in stead of returning an `ImageView` in

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { ... }
```

build something like a `RelativeLayout`, add both the ImageView and the TextView to it, and return the layout.