# Adding multiple images and text in a button

Tags: android, android-button

I can now have a button that contains a single image icon and text, just like below (the red square is the image):

[image]

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/redsquare"
    android:drawablePadding="6dp"
    android:text="Text goes here"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:gravity="left|center" />
```

However, I want to have the button as shown below (two small red squares are two different images):

[image]

I tried to add another drawable in the button, but the result is not as expected. May I ask how can I achieve the same result as above button, please?

Comment: Easiest way would be to define the UI in a layout XML, and add this line to the parent layout: `android:theme="@android:style/Widget.Button"`. I think `RelativeLayout` would be the best here.

Comment: Any details would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Better approach would be to use an [custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333996/button-with-custom-xml-layout) or custom view with either [ripple effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604134/how-to-achieve-ripple-animation-using-support-library) or [custom button selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector) added to the view.

Comment: I am trying to add an `ImageView` on button, but the image cannot be shown. Do you know why?